# Get every table row values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to test this Angular table by verifying every table row data:

Full code: https://pastebin.com/kpiguQCt

```
<div class="ag-center-cols-viewport" ref="eCenterViewport" role="presentation" style="height: calc(100% + 17px);">
   <div class="ag-center-cols-container" ref="eCenterContainer" role="rowgroup" unselectable="on" style="width: 3440px; height: 150px;">
      <div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="99" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="159" col-id="lotCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 600px;  ">Material_66734-GLot</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="120" col-id="warehouseName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 400px;  ">Warehouse_Modify</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="100" col-id="operationCodeName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;  ">Create Inventory</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="101" col-id="completedDateTime" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 200px;  ">2021-08-03T12:29:05.123</div>
      </div>
      <div role="row" row-index="1" aria-rowindex="3" row-id="1" comp-id="102" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(50px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="160" col-id="lotCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 600px;  ">Material_66734-GLot</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="124" col-id="warehouseName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 400px;  ">Warehouse_Modify</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="103" col-id="operationCodeName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;  ">SerialNumber Creation</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="104" col-id="completedDateTime" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 200px;  ">2021-08-03T12:29:03.64</div>
      </div>
      <div role="row" row-index="2" aria-rowindex="4" row-id="2" comp-id="105" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-last" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(100px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="161" col-id="lotCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 600px;  ">Material_66734-GLot</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="128" col-id="warehouseName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 400px;  ">Warehouse_Modify</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="106" col-id="operationCodeName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;  ">SerialNumber Move</div>
         <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="107" col-id="completedDateTime" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 200px;  ">2021-08-03T12:40:48.16</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div"));
        String projectLookupCodes = ".//div[@col-id='warehouseName']";
        String loadContainerSequence = ".//div[@col-id='completedDateTime']";
        String packagedItemCount = ".//div[@col-id='warehouseName']";

        for(WebElement e: tableRows) {
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(projectLookupCodes)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("ProjectLookupCodes: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(projectLookupCodes)).getText());
            }
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(loadContainerSequence)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("loadContainerSequence: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(loadContainerSequence)).getText());
            }
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(packagedItemCount)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("packagedItemCount: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(packagedItemCount)).getText());
            }
            System.out.println("=============================");
        }
```

But I can't get the values. How I can check every table row data and verify the exact values?

Answer (score 1):

1. The xpath what you tried at first is './/div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div' and the variable- tableRows holds List with size of 3 (based on above HTML code added in question). Also, this xpath matches with rows, but not columns.
2. You have written xpaths for projectLookupCodes, loadContainerSequence and packagedItemCount. Instead, try this code to get complete row data at each level:

   ```
    List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div"));     List<Map<String, List>> tableData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList>>();       for (int i = 1; i <= tableRows.size(); i++) {
        // this loop will be executed for 3 iterations
        List<WebElement> eachRow = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div[" + i + "]/div"));
        // Here, this eachRow size would be 4 as each row have 4 columns
        Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
        List list = new ArrayList();
        for (WebElement column : eachRow) {
            list.add(column.getText());
        }
        map.put(("row" + i), list);
        tableData.add(map);
        }
   ```

At last, tableData variable holds data like:

```
[{
    row1: ["Material_66734-GLot", 
            "Warehouse_Modify", 
            "Create Inventory", 
            "2021-08-03T12:29:05.123"]
    }, {
    row2: ["Material_66734-GLot",
            "Warehouse_Modify",
            "SerialNumber Creation",
            "2021-08-03T12:29:03.64"]
    }, {
    row3: ["Material_66734-GLot",
            "Warehouse_Modify",
            "SerialNumber Move",
            "2021-08-03T12:40:48.16"]
    }]
```

Comment: Very strange I get his output: https://pastebin.com/FE3ycSA1

Comment: Yes, each column value of a row are seperated by spaces for your reference. Let us know in which format you are expecting the output?

Comment: I just need to print the result from the table. Format is not important I need to make assert for proper value.

Comment: In that case, just use this code 'for (WebElement column : eachRow) {
     Assert.assertEquals(column.getText(), "EXPECTED VALUE");
 }' and remove System.out.println() listed at last

Comment: I tried this: https://pastebin.com/iXh7ZKWS  As expected it starts to find the values. Is it possible to create a List or Map for each row which holds values and pass the values to compare them? `map.add("Warehouse_Modify");
map.add("Material_66734-GLot");
map.add("some_mane");` or there is something better?

Comment: Replace EXPECTED VALUE with the one what you want to compare..